# How to change a leader in etcd cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, etcd

I have a etcd cluster running on coreOS. The leader was set to the first member I've started (as expected), but I started the wrong one first, so the leader isn't who it's supposed to be.

How do I change the role of a leader to a different member?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. The whole point of leader election is not having to worry about who's leader and who's not.

Comment: @helmbert Sorry for the late reply. I want the master node (will be a master node in kubernetes claster) to also be the leader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood the role of the etcd cluster leader. I was setting up a Kubernetes cluster and I thought the master node should be the etcd cluster leader. But as @heimbert mentioned the point of leader election is that you don't have to worry who the leader is.

Answer (score 2):

To change the leader in the etcd cluster you need to run a command:

```
etcdctl move-leader id-of-the-node-you-want-to-be-the-leader
```

To get `id-of-the-node-you-want-to-be-the-leader` you need to run a command:

```
etcdctl endpoint status -w table
```

Full example with certificates and endpoints - you must adjust the parameters to your configuration of course. First get the table:

```
etcdctl endpoint status -w table \
    --cacert="/ssl/client/ca-client.crt" \
    --cert="/ssl/client/prod-v1-etcd-node-1-client.crt" \
    --key="/ssl/client/prod-v1-etcd-node-1-client.key" \
    --endpoints=127.0.0.1:2379,prod-v1-etcd-node-2:2379,prod-v1-etcd-node-3:2379
```

...then, change the leader:

```
etcdctl move-leader 1f648bfb63561530 \
    --cacert="/ssl/client/ca-client.crt" \
    --cert="/ssl/client/prod-v1-etcd-node-1-client.crt" \
    --key="/ssl/client/prod-v1-etcd-node-1-client.key" \
    --endpoints=127.0.0.1:2379,prod-v1-etcd-node-2:2379,prod-v1-etcd-node-3:2379
```